# CSS styles and Jquery do not get applied to jsp:include file

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, web-applications, include

I am using eclipse and Tomcat 7.

I have an index.jsp page. In the index.jsp file, I include login.jsp file using jsp:include tag. when I first run the application, the page gets rendered as expected.

But when I click on the link in the page that points back to the same index.jsp page, the rendering of the page breaks. Basically the CSS and jquery seems to be gone. Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this?

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slide.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="../pages/login.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <br><br><br>
    <div>
        <a href="pages/index.jsp">Login</a>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Initially, when the application is started, Gets rendered well as follows:**

[image]

**After I click on the "Login" link.** 
[image]

**My file structure:**

[image]

Comment: You're navigating to a page that is in a different folder, resutling in your relative links no longer pointing to the correct files. Your file paths are wrong.

Comment: @KevinB The link is in the index.jsp and the link redirects back to index.jsp, I have attached the image of my folder structures. Thank you

Comment: there's enough to prove my point in your first to images. Note how the first goes to `/MyFirstProject/` while the second goes to `/MyFirstProject/pages/index.jsp` This means on the first one it's looking at `/MyFirstProject/css/style.css` while the second is looking at `/MyFirstProject/pages/css/style.css` which obviously doesn't exist, confirmed by the file-structure you just posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you visit the index page, your css style is accessed like this:

```
/MyFirstProject/css/style.css
```

Once you click on the link, you navigate to

```
/MyFirstProject/pages/index.jsp
```

which then tries to include the following css file:

```
/MyFirstProject/pages/css/style.css
```

which obviously doesn't exist. Modify your script and css includes to be absolute so that navigating to a different folder won't require you changing the file paths.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyFirstProject/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```